# How to automatically convert strings to lists or sets in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say we have this dataframe in Pandas. In my case, I got it as the result of a `pivot_table()` with the aggfunc as `lambda x: x`, because `list` or `set` didn't do the right thing with this kind of data.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [None, "1,2,3", None],
        ["3,4,5", None, "1,4,5"],
        [None, "1,3,6", None],
    ],
    index=["YYZ", "YEG", "BRU"],
    columns=["ANA", "JAL", "KLM"],
)
df
```

I'd like to parse it to change the strings with commas in between to sets. I managed to do it naïvely like this:

```py
for column in df.columns:
    nulls = df[column].isnull()
    for idx in df.loc[nulls, column].index:
        df.at[idx, column] = set()
    for idx in df.loc[~nulls, column].index:
        df.at[idx, column] = set(df.at[idx, column].split(","))
df
```

which gives this:

```
        ANA       JAL       KLM
YYZ     {}        {3, 2, 1} {}
YEG     {5, 4, 3} {}        {5, 4, 1}
BRU     {}        {6, 3, 1} {}
```

What's the right way of doing it in Pandas?

Comment: you should be storing scalars in your dataframe, not sequences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `applymap` with a `lambda`. `lambda` checks if not `None`, then `split` and convert to `set` else return an empty `set`.

**EDIT:** Added `map()` to change datatype of the set items from strings to ints.

```
df.applymap(lambda x: set(map(int, x.split(','))) if x is not None else {})
```

```
           ANA        JAL        KLM
YYZ         {}  {2, 1, 3}         {}
YEG  {5, 4, 3}         {}  {1, 4, 5}
BRU         {}  {6, 1, 3}         {}
```